# Firebase functions doesn't work as expected

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

Firebase functions sometime does not work as expected. Function does not get triggered by the realtime db write. When I checked console log, I found following error. Seems like the function get crashed sometime, it leads to short down periods. Is there a solution for that?

Error 1:

```
Error: set
at Repo_1.Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:399:67)
at Repo_1.Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:306:10)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:286:19
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js:402:17
at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js:435:17)
at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/Connection.js:262:14)
at Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/Connection.js:256:18)
```

Error 2:

```
Error: maxretry
    at Repo_1.Repo.rerunTransactionQueue_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:399:67)
    at Repo_1.Repo.rerunTransactions_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:306:10)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/Repo_transaction.js:286:19
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js:402:17
    at PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/core/PersistentConnection.js:435:17)
    at Connection.onDataMessage_ (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/cjs/src/realtime/Connection.js:262:14)
```

Error 3:

```
[2018-03-28T17:17:52.843Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: transaction at /{SomeaPath}/ failed: disconnect
```

Comment: same issue. did you find solution?